How to simulate and fine tune vacuum tube clipping behaviour for guitar overdrive?
I am looking to create a guitar distortion pedal in which the clipping is similar to that of a vacuum tube but should be tunable.
That is, how do I make a circuit in which I can fine-tune its non-linear U-I behaviour?

The obvious choice in 2024 is to use a DSP, but I suppose you want something analog that has soft clipping.

Take your clean audio and route some of it to a squaring circuit. Remove the DC component and then remix this via an adjustable pot into the clean audio stream. This second harmonic distortion should sound very interesting and mimic a triode quite well. I have not done this because I use old school techniques to make the valvy distortion with solid state parts. Whether you go digital or analog with the square law circuit depends on where your skills and resources are.
